# Error 413 on posts using Requests in celery task

Tags: django, nginx, celery

I do a post using the Requests framework on a worker thread (Celery with RabbitMQ as broker). It works fine most of the time but occasionally I get a 413 (request body too large error). I have been informed the client_max_body_size in nginx is set to 50M, but despite the largest post size being only 3MB, the post occasionally still fails. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Are you using http or https?

Comment: Do you do the post request to the same server (where django is running)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have included the server directive for the webserver listening on port 80. Port 80 is traditionally used for http traffic. However if your application is using https, rather than http, you need to include it in the server directive listening on port 443 serving https as well.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.***.com;

    client_max_body_size 50M;
.....
```

## EDIT:

In response to your clarification in the comments(which seem to have been removed since), I would like to explain the problem you're experiencing on a very high level.

The situation you're encountering is described by this diagram:

[image]

The problematic portion of your process is the **red arrow**, because sometimes you receive a 413 error code when POSTing a large object to another server.

The `nginx.conf` that you can modify on your server **does not affect** the red arrow. Rather, it affects the **dashed green arrow**. The dashed green arrow is a potential POST request from your celery worker to your own nginx server.

For example you might want the celery worker to process a profile picture of your user with some computation heavy algorithm, and therefore trigger the upload asynchronously after it has been processed in your celery worker. The POST request would then be directed at your own domain `http://yourdomain.com/profile_upload` which is affected by your `nginx.conf`.

The outgoing request to another server **is not subject to your server's `nginx.conf`**.

To get around this problem you should talk to the administrator of the server to which your request is going out to, and ask them to increase the `client_max_body_size` on their server.

Comment: It needs to be in that server's config that you're posting to.